# riot.js nested tags - how can I select an inner html element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, riot.js

I have a riot tag which contains a nested tag... 
example:

```
<parent>
<!-- dome html here...-->
     <child></child> <!-- visually - the child is mounted correctly !-->

     <script>
       this.on('mount', function(){
            $('select').material_select();
       });
     </script>
</parent>

<child>
   <select>
       <option values="1">1</option>
       <option values="2">2</option>
       <option values="3">3</option>
   </select>
   <script>
       this.on('mount', function(){
            $('select').material_select();
       });
   </script>
</child>
```

Now, I want to use the Materialize library and jquery to make  the list 
materialize-designed such as in http://materializecss.com/forms.html
It usually works fine when the 'select' tag is in a parent tag!

However, I cant find where to initialize the  `$('select').material_select();`
command in the child, and thus, the select tag in the child tag is not visible!.

I have tried to initialize it inside the on('mount') area both of the parent and the child tags - but it seems as always the $('select') selector return an empty array - any ideas?

Comment: The way I am handling it now is really not optimal... I am initializing the $('select').material_select(); within a function and call it 1000 ms after the mount event fires using setTimeout() - this works but really not elegant - is there is a more elegant way to know when a nested tag is mounted?!

Comment: Have you tried `$('select', this.root).material_select();` in child tag mount event?

Comment: Frustratingly works on my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghstahl/pob86fj3/, but not in my webpacked app.  I had to do the 100ms timer out of my on mount to do the final call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to force the children to update and then call the on('updated') event on the child, because it´s seems that the DOM is not ready onMount. Check this example.

```
<parent>
<!-- dome html here...-->
     <child></child> <!-- visually - the child is mounted correctly !-->

     <script>
       this.on('mount', function(){
            this.update();
       });
     </script>
</parent>

<child>
  <div>
   <select>
       <option values="1">1</option>
       <option values="2">2</option>
       <option values="3">3</option>
   </select>
  </div>
   <script>
       this.on('updated', function(){
            $('select').material_select();
       });
   </script>
</child>
```

online version https://jsfiddle.net/vitomd/Lm4dy21d/5

Comment: Your example works without tricks when using latest (v2.6.1) riot version -> https://jsfiddle.net/qbjw4sq8/

Comment: here is a more complicated variation on Heikki's fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ghstahl/pob86fj3/
I use dynamically created id's and hook up change events.